# Loging to Xing with Curl + Php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make a dashboard application, that among others will retrieve information from a xing account and store it in our database. Right now, we the default oauth implementation, if the user is not logged in, it asks for his permission, and then returns back to the webpage that all the information is shown.

We need to automate the login process, so that every day for example, our php script will run and copy our xing contacts in the database. But we need that happening without manually loging in to Xing.

I have read/tried a lot of the curl/php scripts for logging in a website, but none of them actually worked for xing.

Can someone please provide me with the php script that would just login to xing.com?

Thanks a lot for your time...

Comment: Please post one of your tries and at what point it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Edga. I tried a lot of stuff both for connecting to a normal and secure website, but i haven't kept my code since it didn't work. I know, silly...

Answer (score 0):

Xing seem to have an [API](http://devblog.xing.com/category/api-2/). That would be the vastly superior way to fetch data from them.

Scraping the web site is prone to breaking, and probably against their Terms and Conditions, too.

Comment: I know about their API. We use their API to fetch data. But in order to user their API, you have first to be logged in as a XING user. I am asking, how can i just login to XING from PHP, so that, a physical person doesn't have to be present while inputing username and password in the login form.